# How can I remove constants from a reduced result?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

I am trying to *reduce* some equations and get the final simplified answer. But there are two issues.

*This is just an example to show what my problem is. There are lots of similar samples with the same issue for me*.

```
Reduce[((x >= xP && Mod[x, Abs[1]] == Mod[xP, Abs[1]] && x >= xP &&
     t == tP && z + 2*x*t == zP + 2*xP*tP)) && Not[(xP != 10)], {t,
  xP, zP}]
```

And this the (copy/pasted) output:

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 10 && x == C[1] && t == tP &&
 xP == 10 && zP == -20 tP + 2 t x + z
```

1. How do I get rid of these constants? c1 is an integer, c>=10 and x==c1, so I expect to just see x>=10. I think there must some other functions to give us a nicer output.
2. Why doesn't it replace t and tP? I don't want to see t==tP. We expect only replacement.

Comment: Re (2): By specifying `{t, xP, zP}` for the variables, you ask for a solution for `t`. To get rid of it, mark it for elimination: `Reduce[.., {xP, zP}, {t}]`. Re (1): I'm not sure what will work in general. Reduce is parametrizing the solution set in terms of the integer parameter `C[1]`. It's designed this way. You could replace it thus: `{xP, zP}, {t}] /. C[1] -> x`. I'm not sure that works in all your problems, since it's based on knowing the output of `Reduce`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks that was great, but now the output is this :                                                         x \[Element] Integers && x >= 10 && xP == 10 && zP == -20 tP + 2 tP x + z . Is there anyway not to see "X IS INTEGER"? thanks again

Comment: `Simplify[result, Element[x, Integers]]` is one way, which may do other simplifications. Another is `result /. _Element -> True`, which would remove all domain specifications. I think `x` might have to be an integer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get the desired result:

```
sol = Solve[((x >= xP && Mod[x, Abs[1]] == Mod[xP, Abs[1]] && 
    x >= xP && t == tP && z + 2*x*t == zP + 2*xP*tP)) && Not[xP != 10], 
  {xP, zP}, {tP}, MaxExtraConditions -> All];
Normal@sol

(*  {{xP -> 10, zP -> -20 t + 2 t x + z}}  *)
```

Or to keep the conditions but eliminate the parameters `C[]`:

```
Simplify[sol,
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic,
   (# /. ce_ConditionalExpression :> (ce /. 
         First@Solve[Last@ce, Cases[Last@ce, _C, Infinity], Reals]) &)}
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Appendix*

The OP indicates that the solution in my comment is preferred, so in keeping with SE philosophy, I will include in my answer. The reception of Bob's answer led me to think the OP didn't mind whether the output was in `Solve` or `Reduce` form, so I opted above for `Solve`. Besides, `Normal@Solve[..]` seems so simple.

```
Simplify[
 Reduce[((x >= xP && Mod[x, Abs[1]] == Mod[xP, Abs[1]] && x >= xP && 
       t == tP && z + 2*x*t == zP + 2*xP*tP)) && Not[(xP != 10)],
  {xP, zP}, {tP (* or t *)}
  ] /. C[1] -> x,
 x \[Element] Integers]

(*  x >= 10 && xP == 10 && 2 t (-10 + x) + z == zP  *)
```

I personally was somewhat dissatisfied with this solution because the replacement `C[1] -> x` is predicted to work only after carefully inspecting the output of `Reduce`.  So an approach that focussed narrowly on "*just an example*" seems to lack sufficient robustness. The `Solve` approach in the second solution above, which constructs the replacement `C[1] -> x`, seems more robust.  Probably it could be broken by carefully thinking about what would break it; however, it will work on a wider class of problems than than the narrower class that `C[1] -> x` fixes.  But perhaps the OP's problems all belong to that narrower class.

Comment: To me the best answer  is the one you mentioned in comments because it does not show "if x ......" and i want to reduce, because solve gives me these conditions in the output.( in this answer, the results is shown as somehow conditioned answer ) by the way thanks both answer is good.

Comment: Could you show me a link to a good document that i can learn from? i didn't find in the wolfram website such a deep instructions

Comment: @Azzurro94 You're welcome. I don't have a good reference/tutorial for symbolic equation solving in Mathematica, unfortunately. What I know is built from experience and goes back to before Mathematica, when I studied computer algebra and computational algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Add the condition `Element[x, Integers]` to `Reduce`

```
sol =
  Reduce[((x >= xP && Mod[x, Abs[1]] == Mod[xP, Abs[1]] && x >= xP && 
       t == tP && z + 2*x*t == zP + 2*xP*tP)) && Not[(xP != 10)] && 
    Element[x, Integers], {xP, zP}, {t}, Reals];
```

Convert to a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
sol2 = ConditionalExpression[
  ToRules[And @@ Cases[sol, eq_Equal, 1]] // Simplify, 
  And@@Cases[sol, _?(FreeQ[#, Equal] &), 1]]
```

[image]